# UITextField background property issue in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, background, uitextfield

I would like to create `UITextField` which looks like a Label in normal view and as Text field with custom background in edit mode. I added a "No Border Style" `UITextField` in XIB and set the outlet with name `nameTextField`. I have set a background for `UITextField` in edit mode and `nil` background in view mode on button event, but the image is not appearing after the first disappear in iOS 6.x, everything else works as expected. I have tested in iOS 7.x and it works as expected. The code looks like this,

```
- (IBAction)editButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    editMode = !editMode;
    if (editMode)
    {
        nameTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"textbg.png"];
        nameTextField.enabled = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        nameTextField.background = nil;
        nameTextField.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

**Test case :**

1. Tap Edit Button, to enable editing and show background -> Background appears and field
   is enabled as expected
2. Tap Edit Button again, to disable editing and hide background -> Background disappears as expected
3. Tap Edit Button again, to Enable edit and show background -> **Field is enabled for editing but without background.**

Comment: Can your share the screen shot of the Textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for your comments.

I think this one is an iOS 6.x bug; if the background property of **UITextField** set to **nil** on or after **viewDidAppear**, later changes to the background property will not be drawn.

**The workaround for this issue is to use a blank transparent image instead of nil.** The image can be used in either of the two ways,

1 ) Set the background (textbg.png and blank_image.png) through code; then the code will look like,

```
- (IBAction)editButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    editMode = !editMode;
    if (editMode)
    {
        nameTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"textbg.png"];
        nameTextField.enabled = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        nameTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_image.png"];
        nameTextField.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

2 ) Set the background (textbg.png) and disabled background (blank_image.png) in XIB; then the code will look like,

```
- (IBAction)editButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    editMode = !editMode;
    if (editMode)
    {
        nameTextField.enabled = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        nameTextField.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, we're on iOS 12 now but I've just come across a similar behavior where setting the background color of a `UITextField` worked fine. However, hiding the view and displaying it again would have unexpected results (either background disappears or alpha channel changes). Using an image instead as suggested here fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

In the Interface Builder, just below the place where you set the background image, there should be an option to select a border style, by default it is selected to RoundedRect, select another style and you can immediately see the background image.

Comment: Hi,I have already selected "No Border Style" text field and set the background through code (already posted). I tried setting the background in XIB. If I tapped first time the background disappear as expected, but the image is not appearing if I tapped again.

Comment: This issue getting from device or simulator ?

Comment: Getting on both device and simulator.

Comment: Try this , remove the nameTextField.background = nil; and replace the nameTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];